# the 'vfpoledb.1' provider is not registered on the local machine. yet it is

Tags: visual-foxpro, connectionexception

I'm getting this error:
the 'vfpoledb.1' provider is not registered on the local machine. 64-bit

When running an app from a Windows 2012 Server (x64). The VFP driver is installed.

I even uninstalled it and reinstalled it through the command line running as Admin.

I have compiled the app to x86, and even set the Prefer 32 Bit project setting.

Yet I still get the error on the particular server.

I run the same app on a different Windows 2012 Server (x64) and it works.

Everything I have tried are the things suggested everywhere I can find online.

Looking to see if anyone might have any hints.

I know, VFP is like stone age tech, but that's what I'm stuck with :)

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a web app or a dektop app?

Answer (score 0):

Saying "VFP is like stone age tech" makes me think you don't know really about it much. As of today, there is still an office component called access which they claim to be a database, while it is not, and you still call VFP stone age? Go figure. Something being 32 Bits, and support abandoned by MS doesn't mean it is bad. You shouldn't try to insult current VFP programmers. A seasoned VFP programmer can kick many average .Net developers but with ease, that is a known fact.

Anyway, first download and reinstall the VFPOLEDB provider using its msi file. Second, be sure that you are targeting x86 in your project. It works for me on any 64 bits machine I have tried here and on thousands of customer computers (utilities, activex components, asp.net mvc etc code that I have all written in C#).

And finally, Advantage Database Server is supposed to have an 64 bits version that can be used against VFP database if you want to try (I didn't try using that one).

Comment: Thank you for the political statement my brother and thanks for the rest of the advice! :)